# MySQL Query Where Column Like Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a small project that involves grabbing a list of contacts which are stored for each group. Essentially, the database is set up so that each group has a primary and secondary contact stored as, unsurprisingly, Group.Primary and Group.Secondary. The objective is to pull every Primary and Secondary contact for each Group and display them in a sortable table.

I have the sortable table all worked out, but I have come across a small problem. Each primary and secondary field can have more than one contact separated by a comma. For instance, if Primary contained 123,256 , it would need to pull both Contacts with IDs 123 and 256. I had intended to use a query formatted like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Group G, 
       Contacts C 
 WHERE G.Primary LIKE %C.ID% 
    OR G.Secondary LIKE %C.ID%
```

so that I could just skip the comma part, but I can't seem to find a working query for this.

My question to you is, am I just overlooking something here? Is there a simple query that would let me do this? Or am I better off getting the groups and contacts separately, and combine the two later. I think the former is a little easier to understand when read, which is a plus as this is a shared project, but if that is not possible I will do the latter.

This code is simplified, but it gets the point across.

Comment: You have a one-to-many relationship inside your database. One group has one, or more, contacts associated. Most people solve this by adding a extra table containing the groupid and contact id combinations. This way you can use a normal join to get all the contacts assosiated with the group. Added advantage is that it is a lot faster than having the 'parse' the string with comma separated values each time.

Comment: Sadly, it's a legacy database, and too many systems rely on it to alter the structure, so it has to stay as it is. I'll try the solutions here, see what I can make happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the [MySQL FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Group G 
  JOIN Contacts C ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id, g.primary)
                  OR FIND_IN_SET(c.id, g.secondary)
```

But I highly recommend you normalize the table -- do not store comma delimited lists if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're definitely better off separating those two data values into different tables and then using `JOIN`s to do your linking.  If you were to, say, cast your id fields to strings so you could use the `LIKE` comparison, you'd end up with a bunch of junk matches.  For example, if your primary id is 1, and your secondary is 35, then you'd match on the following (and this list is not exhaustive):

```
1: 1, 2: 35
1: 35, 2: 1
1: 10, 2: 135
1: 431, 2: 3541
```

etc.

What I'd do instead is something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Group G
LEFT JOIN Contacts c1 on g.primary = c1.id
LEFT JOIN Contacts c2 on g.secondary = c2.id
WHERE
c1.id IS NOT NULL
OR
c2.id IS NOT NULL
```

I think that'll get you the data you're really looking for, if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Satan has been in your database, denormalizing it and dooming you to a life of complex and slow queries.

Do you have the ability to alter the structure of the database?  If it's in production, I assume not.  Failing that, you might want to consider creating a normalized table of primary and secondary contacts immediately prior to running this report.

If you can't do that, you need to work out a string matching algorithm that will always work.  The problem with the one that you proposed is that you need to consider a contact id of 23 (or even 3), which will match 23, 123, 223, 231, and so on.  To make that work, you need to add commas to the beginning and ending of both strings you're comparing and then do the LIKE.

Oops.  Or you can use the I-never-knew FIND_IN_SET function described by Ponies, above.

Comment: Preaching to the choir here, but even FIND_IN_SET will match a reversal of the intended match, which is still junk data.  I completely agree that normalization is the way to go here.